# How to create dropdown list which contains all objects of class which foreign key is in our class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I wanted to create a dropdown list for field `Status Status` in `Edit` view for `Person` model. I have seen solutions using ViewBag here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5 but I do not know how to adapt them to my situation.

I have a class Person:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Cell Number")]
        public string CellNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Secondary Number")]
        public string SecondaryPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Pesel")]
        public string Pesel { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

        public  Status Status { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And I have class Status:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public partial class Status {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> M { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I have created controller with read write actions by Entity Framework. This controler has a view EDIT:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Person</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CellNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CellNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CellNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecondaryPhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondaryPhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecondaryPhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pesel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pesel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pesel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.EditorFor(mode => Model.Status);
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I fed database with status instances:

```
 public class PersonInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PersonContext> {
        protected override void Seed(PersonContext context) {
            var persons = new List<Person> { 
             new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
             new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
            };

            persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.Add(person));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
            };

            meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.Add(meeting));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var statuses = new List<Status> {
                new Status{Name = "OK"},
                new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
            };

            statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.Add(status));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

and the result is:

[image]

but I wanted the list of every status existing in my application to choose from. So I wanted a dropdown list of `OK`, `NOT_OK` status to choose from like here:

[image]

---

EDIT: I passed `ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Statuses, "Id", "Name", person.Status);` to the View.  How do I create dropdown List for these values?

Comment: You tagged this question with `html.dropdownlistfor`, but it doesn't appear that you're actually using it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is not the same case. Here I look for objects which are not available by model. They are from other class.

Comment: Your question is in the first sentence?  This seems like ASP.NET MVC 101.  Have you tried reading the tutorials and the documentation for creating a dropdown?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Here it happens just by `EditorFor` http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5   In my case `EditorFor` shows both fields of `STatus` class to fullfil. So I added this in `PersonController` Edit action: `  ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Statuses, "Id", "Name", person.Status);` But I don't know how to create dropdown list for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. You need just one thing: an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. With that, it's a cake walk. So in your controller action, fetch your statuses and select them as `SelectListItem`s:

```
var statusChoices = db.Statuses.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = m.FooProperty,
        Value = m.BarProperty
    });
```

Where `FooProperty` is the property on your `Status` class you want displayed in the drop down list, and `BarProperty` is the property on your `Status` class you want posted as the selected value.

You can then store this in either `ViewBag` or, preferably, as a property on your view model. I'll go with the second option here because I really discourage people from using `ViewBag` as much as possible:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, Model.StatusChoices)
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you look at my answer. It works as it should but it might be really badly done.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of displaying **DropDownList** in MVC.

One way is to create collection of **SelectListItem** in model, and pass it to View.

For example,

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...

        /*public  Status Status { get; set; }*/

        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AllStatuses { get; set; }

        public Person ()
        {
            AllStatuses = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Person();
        model.AllStatuses = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "One",  Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Two",  Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Three",  Value = "3"}
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Person model)
    {
        // Get the selected value
        int id = model.StatusId;
        return View();
    }
}
```

### View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StatusId, Model.AllStatuses)
```

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534564/296861) at SO.

Answer (score 0):

I did(and it works):

In `Person` class:

```
 public  int? StatusId { get; set; }
 public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
```

in GET `Edit` action of controller:

```
  ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Statuses, "Id", "Name", person.StatusId);
```

In POST `Edit` action of controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,CellNumber,SecondaryPhoneNumber,Address,BirthDate,Pesel,Notes,StatusId")] Person person) {
```

In `Edit` view:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("StatusId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The weird** thing is that initial value is not `String.Empty` but actual `Status` of a person.