# how to set a value for the html.DropDownList in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how to set a value for the html.dropdownlist in asp.net mvc 
for example, suppose that we have this list

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Suppliers", Model.PDTO.ProjectSuppliers, new { @class = "text_field multiList hide", @multiple = "multiple" })*@
```

I know that I can use ListBoxFor or DropDownListFor Like this

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Suppliers, Model.PDTO.ProjectSuppliers, new { @class = "text_field multiList hide", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

but I am wondering about how can we do this with the DropDownList, I tried to search in google but I found answers just for `DropDownListFor`.

Any help please.

Comment: If the value of `Suppliers` in an array of values that matches one or more of the values of your options, then those options will be selected. But why would you not use the strongly typed helpers anyway?

Comment: You want to make ProjectSuppliers as IList<SelectListItem>. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24534564/296861)

Comment: I use strongly typed view but when I use Html.DropDownList, it does not select the items and when I use ListBoxFor is selects them :(

Comment: I mean why use `DropDownList()` instead of the **strongly typed** `DropDownListFor()` method. The code you have show works fine in both cases assuming you have set the value of `Suppliers` and the value of `PDTO.ProjectSuppliers` correctly. Show your controller GET method

Comment: You mean your code for 'Html.DropDownList' above is not working?

Answer (score 2):

DropDownList is not strongly typed. To get selected options for DropDownList you should write code in your action.

The following code snippet may help you.

***In your action:***

```
var selectedValue = new List<int> {1, 2};
ViewBag.ProjectSuppliers= new MultiSelectList(SupplierList, "Id", "SupplierName", selectedValue );
```

***In you view:***

```
@Html.DropDownList("Suppliers", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.ProjectSuppliers, "-----Select-----", new { multiple="" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but I know I've used dropdownlist before by loading up an

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItems> selectList
```

in the controller, passing it to the ViewBag

```
ViewBag.selectList = selectList;
```

and then just using

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectList")
```

in the view.

There are overloads for it if you choose to go another route though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx

See the following for a more detailed example of the ViewBag method: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/128/get-the-drop-on-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists

Answer (score 0):

We will have to assign data to dropdownlist from ViewData then we will able to set selected value to dropdownlist, something like this below

```
private ActionResult GetEmployeesForDropDown()
{
    var lstEmployees = new[] 
    {   
        new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp1" }, 
        new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp2" }, 
        new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "Emp3" } 
    };
    var selectList = new SelectList(lstEmployees, "Id", "Name", 0);  
    //Here 0 is the selectedIndex which we are assigning to dropdownlist, we can pass value we want here to set the index
    ViewData["Employees"] = selectList;  
    // dropdownlist datasource which is a employeelist is assigned to a ViewData here
    return View();
}
```

View will look like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddEmployees", (SelectList)ViewData["Employees"], "---Select---", new {@class="DropDownCssIfAny"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
List<Department> departments = dbHR.Departments.OrderBy(d => d.DEPARTMENT_NAME).ToList();
departmentsList = new SelectList(departments, "DEPARTMENT_ID", "DEPARTMENT_NAME", deptInt);
 ViewBag.DepartmentsList = departmentsList;
```

View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("DEPARTMENTS", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DepartmentsList, string.Empty)%>
```